# How can I create a TextField in the Vaadin Grid Editor for a BigDecimal and be able to type in amounts

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8, vaadin-grid

The problem is that as I'm typing the value can be overwritten. For example if I want to type "12.34" but it takes me more than half a second to type the 3 after the period (that is "12.3" then the period is erased and I end up typing "123") which is very annoying. All it takes is for me to look at my sheet of paper as I'm typing and I can't type in any amounts with cents (numbers after the period) without making a ton of data entry errors because the period gets removed.

```
Binder<Pojo> binder;

Binder.Binding<Pojo, BigDecimal> amountEditorBinder = binder.forField(amountTextField)
    .withValidator(DoubleValidator::isValidValue, "Must be valid amount")
    .withConverter(new StringToBigDecimalConverter(new BigDecimal("0"), "Must be an amount"))
    .bind(Pojo::getAmountBigDecimal, AccountEntry::setAmountBigDecimal);

grid.addColumn(Pojo::getAmount)
    .setEditorBinding(amountEditorBinder);

class Pojo
{
    private BigDecimal amount; // with getters and setters
}
```

I suspect this issue is due to the line:

```
.withConverter(new StringToBigDecimalConverter(new BigDecimal("0"), "Must be an amount"))
```

but without it I can't convert the value of the TextField to the value in the Pojo. Is there to fix that?

Comment: Especially for monetary amounts, I have been implementing better converters. You may want to convert `12.` to `12.00` and sometimes you want special handling of `,` and `.`. Maybe improving converter would help with data entry errors.